# vscode-insiders warnings are marked red. Disabling them mask even those "necessary"

Tags: visual-studio

Satisfied use vs-insiders with python extension. Unfortunately I noticed that the latest releases highlight the warnings with a red underline. If I disable pylance all warnings disappear including those that might be useful e.g. "Module xyz is missing" and its quick fix. The solution suggested by pylance is to add "#type: ignore" which seems like a big nonsense to me. Is it possible to reset vscode-insiders as it was about ten days ago? Or is it necessary to downgrade pylance?